# How to stop the Tor Browser from storing sensitive data in its .local directory?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

The tor-browser is saving download history on-disk in

```
tor-browser/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

and files in

```
tor-browser/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/
```

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: A similar question also was asked here: http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/849/88

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2013 Runa Sandvik did a forensic analysis. You can see the results in the PDF titled »[Forensic Analysis of the Tor Browser Bundle
on OS X, Linux, and Windows](https://research.torproject.org/techreports/tbb-forensic-analysis-2013-06-28.pdf)«. Runa found the issues you asked for plus entries in the `.bash_history` and `.xsession-errors`. There are bug reports [#8695](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8695) and [#8706](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8706) which deal with those findings.

At the moment there is no official or automated solution. Your best bet is to remove those files by hand or use a live CD like [tails](http://tails.boum.org/).