# Tor and Folder Lock

Tags: anonymity, security

I'm writing a novel, and one of my characters is into some illegal activities on the web. He's ultra-paranoid about security, so uses Tor...but he doesn't want anyone who might snoop in his computer files to know he's installed the Tor browser. So here's my question: On a PC, can the Tor program folder be placed in a file-security app like Folder Lock, or does it need to stay in the Program Files folder?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Tor Browser can be put anywhere, e.g. in an encrypted volume and should (at least by design) not leak elsewhere. See https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#disk-avoidance for implementation details.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. As said [in the comments](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/17402/tor-and-folder-lock#comment19616_17402), Tor can be run from pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser can be used as a so-called portable app. This means you download the software and extract it. You can extract the software basically to any folder, device, etc. So some people use it on a USB stick or put it into their local folder. You can simply click on start Tor Browser and the software starts.

The answers to the question »[Are browsing files stored locally?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/849/88)« describe that Tor tries to not write any files to the local drive. So also the fact that Tor is used is quite hidden.